# Dynamically load list-items and sort them, 2 scripts both work apart, but they don't work together. (JSFiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, sorting

I have made a script to load list-items dynamically via JSON and I found a script to sort them by date.

However, they don't work together, if I put them together the list-items get loaded but not sorted,

Script 1 (to load the list-items): [JSFiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/vnuJ2/1/)

Script 2 (to sort the list-items): [JSFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/kULx3/3/)

As you can see, they both work. But when I put them together I just get:

```
<ul class="datacursusul">
  <li class="21/05/2014">Wo 21 mei 2014</li>
  <li class="05/01/2014">Do 05 januari 2014</li>
</ul>
```

**What I want:**

```
<ul class="datacursusul">
  <li class="05/01/2014">Do 05 januari 2014</li>
  <li class="21/05/2014">Wo 21 mei 2014</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your JSFiddle to combine the two scripts. I think the problem might have been that you were trying to sort the list before the content was loaded. The following line must be called *after* the list is populated with the loaded content:

```
$('.datacursusul').sortChildren(ddmmyyyClassSort);
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnuJ2/2/)

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! (only I had to make the datacursusul an unique class but that is fixed also.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the list hasn't loaded when the sort is being fired? Have you tried the sort call by adding a .done() call?

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

See the second to last example.